# How to connect a node.js webapp to a postgresql database running on Azure using system assigned managed identity

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, prisma, azure-managed-identity

We are working on a project where we need to connect a node.js Azure webapp to a postgresql flexible server using managed identities.

This is described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity but the solution is not OK, since it would require getting new tokens all the time.

Therefore, we are looking at a solution involving service connector described here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-connector/how-to-integrate-postgres

So far we managed to

- create a Microsoft.ServiceLinker/Linker object

  ```
             "inputs": {
                   "authInfo": {
                       "authType": "systemAssignedIdentity",
                       "userName": "uName"
                   },
                   "clientType": "nodejs",
                   "linkerName": "linkerName",
                   "resourceUri": <Id of the web app>
                   "targetService": {
                       "id": <id of the posgres db>,
                       "type": "AzureResource"
                   }
               },
  ```

  This step automatically adds environment variables to the web app
  AZURE_POSTGRESQL_POSTGRESQL_HOST , _USER, _DATABASE, _PORT, _SSL
- add the user in the postgres database

  ```
     uName | Create role, Create DB | {azure_pg_admin}, effectively registered as admin user of type principalId
  ```
- We assume this is all working as on the Azure portal, we can validate the Service connection (go to webapp -> Service Connector

[image]

The last step (we assume) is to configure prisma/node.js to use these environment variables to connect to the database (through the service linker)

We've tried the following database url and many variations

```
postgresql://${Azure_POSTGRESQL_USER}@${Azure_POSTGRESQL_HOST}:${Azure_POSTGRESQL_PORT}/${Azure_POSTGRESQL_DATABASE}
```

No matter what we try, we always get

Authentication failed against database server at `XXX.postgres.database.azure.com`, the provided database credentials for `uName` are not valid.

So there are a few questions :

- Is the reasoning correct that - when using serviceLinker, we would not have to fetch tokens all the time, but this resource would take care of that for us ?
- How to we tell prisma to use the service linker in order to get to the postgres database ?
- How should we configure node.js/prisma to get it working ?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to connect to the PostgreSQL database using a connection string that includes the username, host, port, and database name, but not the password. When using managed identities, the password is typically a token that's obtained from the Azure AD service. The Service Connector should handle obtaining this token for you, but you'll need to include it in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Nurul Sundarani. I was hoping that the service connector would take care of the authentication & token management. Dynamic connection parameters are quite difficult using node.js/prisma - see also https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7869